# How to test for approximate equality of generic classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, equality, python-typing

I'm trying to find out if two classes are equivalent, ignoring types parameters. Say I have

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Generic[T]):
    pass

class B(Generic[T], A[T]):
    pass

class X:
    pass
```

I'd like each following row to be equivalent

```
Generic, Generic[T]
A, A[T], A[str], A[int]
B, B[T], B[str], B[int]
X
```

None of `is`, `==`, `isinstance`, `type`, or `__class__` work. Comparing `__name__` is fragile to someone defining another class with the same name.

For bonus points*, I'd also be interested in an additional way to test equivalence of

```
A, A[T], A[str], A[int], B, B[T], B[str], B[int]
```

*not a bounty :p

(The context is that I'd like to find all the subclasses of a class other than `Generic`)

Answer (score 0):

To recover `A` from `A[T]`, you can use the [`__origin__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e022bbc169ca1428dc3017187012de17ce6e0bc7/Lib/typing.py#L609) attribute, which for `A` will be `None`.

```
def compare(a, b):
    if hasattr(a, "__origin__") and hasattr(b, "__origin__"):
        a_origin = a.__origin__ or a
        b_origin = b.__origin__ or b
        return a_origin == b_origin
    else:
        return a == b

compare(A, A[int])  # True
compare(A, B[int])  # False
compare(A, A)  # True
compare(X, X)  # True
```

According to the linked comment, `__origin__` should be available for `Union`, `Optional`, `Generic`, `Callable`, and `Tuple`.

It's worth noting that this is an implementation detail.  Using this is opening yourself up to the risk of the implementation changing without warning.